How to resolve an error when creating a Publisher in SQL Server 2022 on Ubuntu?
I'm setting up SQL Server 2022 replication on Ubuntu Linux. I have two instances running on separate Ubuntu servers. I want to set up transactional replication between them, but I'm encountering an error when trying to create a Publisher.
Here's what I've done so far:
1- I installed SQL Server 2022 on both Ubuntu servers.
(Microsoft SQL Server 2022 (RTM-CU12-GDR) (KB5036343) - 16.0.4120.1 (X64))
2- I set up a Distributor on one of the instances.
3- I'm trying to create a Publisher on the same instance, but I get an error.
Has anyone encountered a similar issue or knows how to resolve it? What are the common causes for errors when creating a Publisher in SQL Server on Linux?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Here some screenshots: (after part 3 there is nothing just go away!)



I expect:
The wizard of "New publication" show and I can setup publication.

Firstly, it would be helpful to paste the text of that last error message, so that other users can find the question. Is that IP number for your local host or for a different server? There is a similar question on dba,stackexchange.com but it doesn't have an answer. You might contemplate whether you need to add a publisher when adding a distributor, or whether adding a distributor enables publishing for you.

TITLE: New Publication Wizard
192.168.47.139 must be enabled as a Publisher before you can create a publication.
For help, click: https://go.microsoft.com:80/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&ProdVer=20.1.10.0&EvtSrc=Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.PubWizardErrorSR&EvtID=WarningPublisherNotEnabled&LinkId=20476

The IP number is for host that install on VMWARE. and I connected to this server with ssms on my local machine

I have same problem, can you help me please!

i have multiple ubuntu servers and always have the same problem, after a lot of do and remove i don´t know how but most times it finally works, problem is than replication can´t be done connecting over IP you need to connect using servername (select @@servername to get it), but how can we connect to a ubuntu server without management studio using name instead of ip, so most times i need to go to C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc edit hosts file and add server ip and servername, after that connection throught management studio works
